# Firebase Authentication SLA

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been having a hard time finding the SLA behind Google Firebase Authentication. According to [Service Level Agreement for Hosting and Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/terms/service-level-agreement/), Firebase shall be available with a Monthly Uptime Percentage of at least 99.95%. Does it apply to the Authentication Services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I got from Google Support when I asked about the differences between Firebase Auth and Cloud Identity Platform.

> The reason for the pricing difference
>   between Firebase Auth and Cloud Identity Platform is Cloud Identity
>   Platform offers a SLA of 99.95% while Firebase Auth has no SLA.

They also mentioned other reasons (ex: SAML and Multitenancy) which is unrelated to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you upgrade to Enterpirse tier then you get the same SLA agreement as Identity Platform. See statement below (complete with typo), on this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth#identity-platform-features) .

> Blockquote
> Upgraded prpjects get uptime guarantees for Auth services according to the Identity Platform Service Level Agreement (SLA) and access to enterprise-grade support.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/sla) is link to Identity Playform SLA, which specifies 99.95% uptime, with credits being given if the Service Level Objective (SLO) is not met.